# Summary comment on github pull request from different Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, github, notifications

I have multiple jobs for one Pull requests running on Jenkins.

When a build is done, a comment is posted by a github account to inform it was done, so people get a notification.
It was fine when it was one job per pull request but now it is more spam than anything else.

One simple solution would be to have notifications on build check but it is not provided by github.

Another way would be to get a summary from those jobs when all are done, but I also don't have any idea on how to proceed on this.

Would there be a more cleaner way or a plugin doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [MultiJob](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) plugin.

Create a parent Job and under that add all your jobs. And configure in such a way that, it triggers the parent job which in turn triggers the child job.

This way, it will notify the github only when all the child jobs are completed.